# How evaluate this integral in cartesian coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I can evaluate this with polar coordinates, but is it possible in cartesian coordinates?

$$
    \int\limits_{z=-1}^{1} \int\limits_{y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y=\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int\limits_{x=-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{x=\sqrt{1-y^2}} 1 dx\,dy\,dz$$

Inner integral:
$$\int\limits_{x=-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{x=\sqrt{1-y^2}} 1 dx= 2\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Second integral:
$$
\int\limits_{y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y=\sqrt{1-x^2}}2\sqrt{1-y^2}
$$

Substitution:
$$
t=\sqrt{1-y^2}
$$

$$
\frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
$$

$$
dt=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy
$$
And I'm stuck here....

Comment: Is there any reason for doing the integration in Cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to calculate the volume common to two right circular cylinders of unit radius intersecting perpendicularly along their axes.

As stated, your limits of integration are not OK: Once you've integrated with respect to $x$ at the first step, subsequent limits of integration can't depend on $x$ (or else the integral would depend on $x$, which it doesn't).

If I've correctly guessed your intent, you want
$$
\int_{z=-1}^{1} \int_{y = -\sqrt{1 - z^{2}}}^{y = \sqrt{1 - z^{2}}} \int_{x = -\sqrt{1 - z^{2}}}^{x = \sqrt{1 - z^{2}}} dx\, dy\, dz
  = \dots = 4\int_{z=-1}^{1} (1 - z^{2})\, dz
  = \frac{16}{3}.
$$